# Property 'formGroup' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular

Hi I am new to angular and i am getting this this error message " Property 'formGroup' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor
" but i have declared formGroup and i don't  why i get this error

```
import { FormControl, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthServiceService } from '../auth-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup:FormGroup;
  constructor(private authService:AuthServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }
  initForm(){
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
    })
  }
  loginProces(){
    if(this.formGroup.valid){
      this.authService.login(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(result=>{
        if(result.success){
          console.log(result);
          alert(result.message);
        } else {
          alert(result.message);
        }

      })
    }
    alert("hi");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

no, you have to initialize every variable or assign it in the constructor since you have strict mode activated. You can fix your error like this:

```js
constructor(private authService:AuthServiceService) { 
  this.initForm();
}

ngOnInit(): void {}
```

Comment: thank @Zerotwelve . but it doesn't work forme

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just mark it as existing value:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup!: FormGroup;
  constructor...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the value at the variable definition.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
    });
```

Comment: this one is work , but my api doesn't call?

Comment: You can remove `this.initForm();` from `ngOnInit`.